# on-Premises to Azure Migration possible ways

Tags: azure, active-directory, migration, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

can any one please tell how many possible way are there to migrate from on-premises to azure

i am planning to migrate active directory to azure

ex:i have AD with some set of polices and different user's in groups i need to move whole AD without any down time
is it possible..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can any one please tell how many possible way are there to migrate
>   from on-premises to azure

As a workaround, we can deploy a site-to-site VPN between Azure and your on-prem, then create an Azure VM, join this VM to your on-prem AD, install Active directory on it, sync your settings to this new VM.

Also we can use **ADMT tool** to do it, please refer to this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx).

By the way, here are some architectures about on-prem AD and Azure AD, please refer to [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/).